# How to Prepare Text for Machine Learning pipeline with compiled Regular Expressions and/or List Comprehension?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, list-comprehension

I am trying to prepare text in a Python function for a machine learning pipeline and I am having trouble to get the correct output. So, I want to lowercase all words, replace symbols by spaces, delete symbols and remove stopwords from nltk. I tried all kinds of different approaches from list comprehension to regex pattern matching, but I still can't get it right. Please help out! Here are the necessary imports and the basic function:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

import re
```

Here is the function:

```
REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def text_prepare(text):
"""
    text: a string

    return: modified initial string
"""

lower = text.lower() # lowercase text
space_replace = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(" ",lower) #replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text
nosymb = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub("",space_replace) # delete symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text
text = [word for word in nosymb if word not in STOPWORDS] # delete                                                                                                             stopwords from text

return text
```

Here is a test function:

```
def test_text_prepare():
    examples = ["SQL Server - any equivalent of Excel's CHOOSE function?",
            "How to free c++ memory vector<int> * arr?"]
    answers = ["sql server equivalent excels choose function", 
           "free c++ memory vectorint arr"]
    for ex, ans in zip(examples, answers):
    if text_prepare(ex) != ans:
        return "Wrong answer for the case: '%s'" % ex
return 'Basic tests are passed.'
```

Here is my test result:

```
print(test_text_prepare())
Wrong answer for the case: 'SQL Server - any equivalent of Excel's CHOOSE function?'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating the words as separate symbols in `[word for word in nosymb if word not in STOPWORDS]`. Besides, you do not strip leading/trailing spaces and do not "shrink" excess spaces that result from your previous cleanup operations.

Here is an updated method:

```
def text_prepare(text):
    """
    text: a string
        return: modified initial string
    """
    lower = text.lower() # lowercase text
    space_replace = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(" ",lower) #replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text
    nosymb = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub("",space_replace) # delete symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text
    text = re.sub(r"\s*\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(STOPWORDS)), "", nosymb) # delete STOPWORDS
    return re.sub(r" {2,}", " ", text.strip())
```

The `re.sub(r"\s*\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(STOPWORDS)), "", nosymb)` part removes all stopwords matched as whole words (`\b` is a word boundary).

The `re.sub(r" {2,}", " ", text.strip())` part trims the string and shrinks all spaces to single spaces inside the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wiktor! It helped :)

Answer (score 1):

text = [word for word in nosymb if word not in STOPWORDS] treats each each character as separate symbol.
try this:

text = ' '.join([word for word in nosymb.split() if word not in STOPWORDS])

It first splits the text into a list of words and then combines them form a string.

Here is the function:

```
def text_prepare(text):

    text = text.lower()# lowercase text
    text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(" ",text)# replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text
    nosymb = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub("",text)# delete symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text
    text = ' '.join([word for word in nosymb.split() if word not in STOPWORDS]) # delete stopwords from text
    return text
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def text_prepare(text):
    """
        text: a string

        return: modified initial string
    """
    text = text.lower()# lowercase text
    text_first = re.sub(REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE,' ',text)# replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text
    text_second = re.sub(BAD_SYMBOLS_RE,'',text_first)#text.remove(BAD_SYMBOLS_RE)# delete symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text
    text = ' '.join([w for w in text_second.split() if not w in STOPWORDS])# delete stopwords from text
    return text
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Comment: Okay , I will do it from next time . Thanks @Chris